# Общий Callback для нескольких async функций

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как лучше сделать если нужно запустить несколько асинхронных функций (их может быть от одной до десятка) и собрать их ответы в один JSON, сами функции делают обращение в сеть и возвращают JSON'ы, желательно отлавливать часть функций которые вывалились с ошибками но при этом возвращать JSON'ы тех что отработали корректно.
ps: deassync и подобное не предлагать, хотелось бы сделать это в асинхронном стиле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const array=[1,2,3,4,5];
const getJSON = (n, cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(Math.random()>.5){
      cb('example error');
    }else{
      cb(null,{[n]:'example result'}); 
    }
  }, Math.random()*1111)
}

const promises =[];
for(var i in array){
  promises.push(new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
    getJSON(array[i],(err,res) => {
      if(err){
        // Обрабатываем ошибку
        console.error(err);
      }
      resolve(res || err);
    })
  ))
}
Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(err =>{
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: буду курить Promise'ы , хотя раньше старался их избегать.